# Are there alternatives to Firebug's HTML panel?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I have always been using Chrome, but recently I came across a very strange HTML  + CSS problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424997/some-component-not-displaying-with-firefox-good-in-chrome), which causes a part of my page not to be displayed in Firefox. That is when I had to use Firebug to debug the page. But there are some very annoying problems with Firebug in comparison to Chrome's DevTools:

1. You can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo changes of the HTML.
2. You can't have an HTML + Console view. Everytime I run some JavaScript function to change the HTML from the console I have to switch between the *Console* and the *HTML* panel.
3. You can't drag and drop HTML elements.

Firebug is very popular. If I can't get along with it, I'd need some other tool to achieve what I want. So, did I miss something about Firebug? And is there a substitution for Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to Firebug in Firefox are the [built-in Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), which can be opened via <kbd>F12</kbd> when Firebug is not installed or via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

They allow you to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and to use drag & drop to move HTML elements. Firebug has an enhancement requests for both, though these features didn't get implemented yet. See [issue 2656](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fbug/issues/2656) and [issue 2569](https://code.google.com/archive/p/fbug/issues/2569) .

Note that Firebug also allows to show the command line within the other panels. You just need to click the command line popup button ( [image: Command Line Popup Button]
 ).